# Adding new iPhone UDIDs to provision profile without an apple dev account

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm part of the design (I've had experience with python, php, jquery, and java, but never ObjC) team for our application and was handed off some of the developer responsibilities with our iPhone developer went on his vacation.  From the developer, I have the project source, his p12 private key, and the mobileprovision file.

Already, I've encountered this error when attempting to build the application on a device:

```
Code Sign error:
  The identity 'iPhone Developer: xxxxxx xxxxx (xxxxxxxxxx)' doesn't match any valid
  certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

despite XCode apparently recognising the distro and keychain (I used `security import xx.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` to import the `p12` file; and there are both the private key and the iPhone Distribution: xxxx xxxxxxx certificate in the keychain GUI.

This I am pretty sure I can solve, but my main concern is whether I can add new UDIDs for the beta tests, which are occurring next week.  The methods I've seen all involve adding devices via Apple's dev centre, and then downloading; i.e. no way to add UDIDs locally.  Our developer is running it off of his personal Apple Dev license ($99 one), which we don't have the password for.

So main question: is there any way to add UDIDs to our distro WITHOUT using the Apple dev centre (i.e. locally), or worse case, can I register my account as an apple developer and then add the UDIDs to that new account to distribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without being able to access his Developer account there is no way for you to create new provisioning files (for extra UUID's) for his account. To add more UUID's you will have to create your own account and setup the project with those certificates and provisioning files.

Of course you could ask the developer to add the UUID's to his account and create a new provisioning file for you. It just depends how many of his 100 UUID's per year he has used up.

If you sign up for your own account, read up on ad hoc distribution. [Apple has plenty of documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/000-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH1-SW1). The following chapters will be of use:

- [Managing Devices and Digital Identities](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW2)
- [Distributing Applications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2)

......[but sometimes guides are easier to follow](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/23/devsugar-a-better-way-to-share-ad-hoc-builds/).

Comment: Cool, thank you.  He's actually completely out of contact (Safari type thing), so I'll have to make the new account.  Wanted to get confirmation before doing so though, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The only way to add new UDIDs is via iTunes connect.

You'll have to contact your developer and either ask him for the password, or tell him the UDIDs so he can regenerate the profiles.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have to set up the new account.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the full source code, and an apple developer account, you could create a private beta test.

You will need to build and code sign your app with a Ad-Hoc Distribution Profile.

The limit is 100 devices, but you can produce multiple Ad-Hoc Distribution Profiles.

Each Ad-Hoc Profile can be attached to a select number of devices.

When Devices are added - you will need to get a new Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile to distribute, but that should get you through a limited beta test.

If you need more information - send me a quick message.  (You may have some issues helping your beta - testers install on VISTA and Windows-7) so learn about IPA files.

"So main question: is there any way to add UDIDs to our distro WITHOUT using the Apple dev centre (i.e. locally), or worse case, can I register my account as an apple developer and then add the UDIDs to that new account to distribute?"